# Корректно ли инициализация IIFE с оператором new

Tags: javascript, jquery, шаблоны-проектирования

Корректно ли создавать функцию IIFE через оператор new, какие есть минусы такой реализации?

```js
var $$ = {};
$$.f = new (function(){
  this.alrt = function()
  {
    alert('alert');
  }
})();

$$.f.alrt();
```

Comment: в данном случае нет IIFE

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае нет `IIFE`. Обычный вызов конструктора с параметрами.

Единственное отличие от привычного конструктор, отсутствие идентификатора, если его добавить

```
$$.f = new (function MyFunc(){
  this.alrt = function()
  {
    alert('alert');
  }
})();
```

А затем объявить MyFunc с помощью декларации

```
function MyFunc(){
  this.alrt = function()
  {
    alert('alert');
  }
}
```

Получим привычный вызов конструктора:

```
$$.f = new MyFunc();
```

---

Если же действительно использовать `IIFE`, можно заметить ошибку, так как в данном случае функция ничего не возвращает, а `undefined` не может использоваться в качестве конструктора.

```js
var $$ = {};
$$.f = new(function() {
  this.alrt = function() {
    alert('alert');
  }
}());

$$.f.alrt();
```

Comment: Т.е. $$.f получает объект анонимной функции? Если нет IIFE, почему код внутри блока запускается сразу(Например если указать alert() после this.alrt)?

Comment: @Сергей, первая часть ответа как раз об этом - ты просто вызываешь функцию как конструктор.